# Ansible - How to select Element in output

Tags: ansible

Im newbie when it comes to ansible started just a week ago. I was playing around with playbooks and ad-hoc command i run ad-hoc command ansible ansiblenodes -m setup -a "filter=ansible_mounts"

```
192.168.75.31 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_mounts": [
            {
                "block_available": 217708,
                "block_size": 4096,
                "block_total": 259584,
                "block_used": 41876,
                "device": "/dev/sda1",
                "fstype": "xfs",
                "inode_available": 523952,
                "inode_total": 524288,
                "inode_used": 336,
                "mount": "/boot",
                "options": "rw,seclabel,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota",
                "size_available": 891731968,
                "size_total": 1063256064,
                "uuid": "8a896a10-d8b0-4c95-9743-69b213b47f5a"
            },
            {
                "block_available": 2145829,
                "block_size": 4096,
                "block_total": 3273216,
                "block_used": 1127387,
                "device": "/dev/mapper/rhel-root",
                "fstype": "xfs",
                "inode_available": 6400742,
                "inode_total": 6551552,
                "inode_used": 150810,
                "mount": "/",
                "options": "rw,seclabel,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota",
                "size_available": 8789315584,
                "size_total": 13407092736,
                "uuid": "9fe9a7c9-613e-428d-b255-93f0006cf9ad"
            }
        ],
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

Now if i want to write a playbook how should i mention that only display Mount point and its available space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you only want to display this data not to do anything with it:

```
---

- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: show filesystems
      debug:
        msg: "mount: {{ item.mount }}, available: {{ item.size_available | human_readable }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_mounts }}"
      loop_control:
        label: ""
```

This playbook will display mountpoint and avaiable size. I used loop_control to not show every item with all properties in Ansible output.

Comment: Thanks this is what i wanted, is it possible you can share some online documentation so that i can i understand all these all elements. Thanks

Comment: @OmiPenguin Official Ansible doc is great so you can just dig into it: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/
In this example I used debug module, loops and filters.